# How to avoid scrolling when resizing the page?

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs` that stack horizontally on each other.

Each `div` occupies 100% of the view-port.

```
.section{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

In each `div` there is an anchor to the other div.

```
<div class="first section ">
<a name="first-section">&nbsp;</a>
<p>Click <a href="#second-section">here</a> to go to the second section</p> 
</div>

<div class="second section">
<p>Click <a href="#first-section">here</a> to go to the first section</p> 
</div>
<a name="second-section">&nbsp;</a>
```

My goal is to show the content of only one `div` each time. But when one is on the second section  `div` and resize the page, the two `divs` are showned when the page is resized to its initial size.

How can I avoid scrolling up when the page is resize?
I have `body{overflow:hidden;}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the div to `position:fixed`, so it's always relative to the viewport. Then hide all the divs except the first one by default, and show the one when it's on `:target`.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/e45zy0kq/)**

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; }

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.section:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
.first {
  background: lightblue;
}
.second {
  background: lightgreen;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="first section" id="first-section">
  <p>Click <a href="#second-section">here</a> to go to the second section</p>
</div>

<div class="second section" id="second-section">
  <p>Click <a href="#first-section">here</a> to go to the first section</p>
</div>
```

Or, use `z-index` with different values, and move the div on top when it's on `:target`.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uwh0pk7z/)**

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; }

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.section:target {
  z-index: 3;
}
.first {
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 2;
}
.second {
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="first section" id="first-section">
  <p>Click <a href="#second-section">here</a> to go to the second section</p>
</div>

<div class="second section" id="second-section">
  <p>Click <a href="#first-section">here</a> to go to the first section</p>
</div>
```

---

*Note, both approaches require each div to have a solid background defined.*